# What is the equivalent data type in WatchOS 5.0 for HKClinicalRecord?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watch, healthkit, hl7-fhir

I am working in `iOS 12.0` and `WatchOS 5.0`.
I am downloading health data from `FHIR` providers in mobile and want to synch back with apple watch. I see there is [HKClinicalRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkclinicalrecord) which has a property of type [HKClinicalType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkclinicalrecord/2976201-clinicaltype)

> `HKClinicalType` is supported in both iOS `12.0` and `WatchOS 5.0` but unfortunately `HKClinicalRecord` is supported only in `iOS 12.0`.

What can be used in watch side as equivalent to `HKClinicalRecord`? Do I need to implement custom data type myself for performing data sync?

Comment: Sounds like API question to iOS. Do you know what FHIR resource `HKClinicalRecord` is representing/mapping to?

Comment: It has a property HkClinicalType which can hold any type of FHIR resources AFAIK.  Correct me if i am wrong. @EL